# How to export finished design as one file in Adobe XD

Tags: adobe-xd

I tried to export my design as one (image) file from Adobe XD. I tried 'file > export' option, but this results in exporting every assets individually. What I want is to export my finished design as one file as it looks in Adobe XD. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Select an artboard, then use the "File > Export > Selected..." (⌘-e) menu option

Answer (score 0):

if you want to have a full height of a web UI, first of all, you need to build an artboard, you can drag it to the custom hight that you need.
after that move all of your project elements to that artboard
then select that artboard and ctrl+E ( or ⌘+E for macOS ) and export it.